# Only trigger Iron Ajax in Custum Elements

Tags: ajax, polymer

I'm struggling with Googles Polymer a bit. I have created a website with a regular index.html with some pages (sections) on it, handled by the routing.html. So far so good - awesome and fast. Now my problem:

In the pages, (in the same index.html file), I load several custom elements, which have some iron ajax calls to my database. Everything works fine. However, if I interact with data on the database on one subpage (in a custom element), some of the other pages' content should change upon that. The problem is that when the database is changed, the iron-ajax's of other subpages do not automatically reload, so I have to force refresh the site to view data changes.

Is there some way to fix this? For example, trigger a iron-ajax element of a certain custom element, from within another custom element?

Thanks for thinking along!

Rogier

Answer (score 0):

You can always call the generateRequest() function on the iron ajax element to cause it to redo its call.  You can of course do this by exposing a function on your custom element which can be called by the higher level elements if you want do do it across the dom tree of custom elements.